# How to install /usr/bin/npm with Docker

Tags: docker, npm, dockerfile

I have the following Dockerfile. It correctly installs `/usr/bin/node` but not `/usr/bin/npm`. What do I need to add/change to fix this?

```
FROM php:8.3-apache
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y gnupg && \
    mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings && \
    curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource-repo.gpg.key | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg && \
    NODE_MAJOR=21 && \
    echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_$NODE_MAJOR.x nodistro main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list && \
    apt-get install -y zip mariadb-client libmagickwand-dev chromium nodejs && \
    docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql exif && \
    a2enmod headers rewrite
ENV PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH="/usr/bin/chromium"
```

```
$ which node
/usr/bin/node
$ which npm
$
```

Comment: it should come with nodejs, after adding the gpg key, you did not do `sudo apt update`, does running that before apt-get install nodejs change anything?

Comment: Also chekc the $PATH and you might want to add usr/local/bin to the $PATH if not there already. Otherwise go for `apt-get install npm` but this was never necessary for a long time.

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin Running `apt update` after adding the gpg key worked. Thanks. If you add it as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: What do you actually need it for?  Can you use a second build stage `FROM node:21` to build a frontend application into static files, maybe?

Comment: @DavidMaze for https://spatie.be/docs/browsershot/v4/requirements. Needs to be given the node and the npm binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not run `[sudo] apt update` after adding nodesource to the keyring.

```bash
apt update && apt-get install -y zip mariadb-client libmagickwand-dev chromium nodejs && \
...
```

This should work. Otherwise try inspecting the `$PATH` and check if `/usr/local/bin` is there, if not add it. You last option (which was not necessary for a long time) is to do `sudo apt-get install npm`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to install both via the [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/)

```
COPY --from=node:20 /usr/local/ /usr/local/
ENV PATH="/usr/local/bin:${PATH}"
```